# Getting Multiple Objects using Django rest_framework RetrieveAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Currently I have this class inside my shop's view.py

```
class ShopDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):

    queryset = Shop.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShopDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'Suburb'
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

And my shop's urls.py which displays this specific api:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', ShopListAPIView.as_view(), name = 'list' ),
    url(r'^(?P<Suburb>\w+)/$', ShopDetailAPIView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
]
```

The aim of the `ShopDetailAPIView` class is to display a filtered version of the data stored inside the database. So that if a user enters

```
 http://example.com/shop/locationname
```

The link will display Django Rest Framework API according to the location.

The problem I am facing is that when there are more than one objects, the page returns:

```
get() returned more than one Shop -- it returned 3!
```

I think my solution is to change my `queryset` to

```
queryset = Shop.Objects.filter(Suburb = suburb)
```

However I have no idea how to implement this using `RetrieveAPIView`.

I know there are alternatives such as `django-filter` which would work perfectly in this situation. However is there any way to implement my code above to show more than 3 objects?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `RetrieveAPIView` for several instances.
However, you likely want some filtering. I'd recommend using url arguments for that along with the `ListAPIView`:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url

Comment: Took me a while to figure out how filtering against the URL works, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of [RetrieveAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview)

> Used for read-only endpoints to represent a **single model instance**.

`RetrieveAPIView` is used to serialize and return ***exactly one object***, which is returned by either `get_object(self)` method or by a lookup on queryset.

If you want to display/return multiple filtered objects, you can use [ListAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview). Your filtering can be done in the `get_queryset(self)` method, something as following

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Shop.Objects.filter(Suburb = self.suburb)
```

Or better, use drf's built-in [Filtering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering).